# Acumatica IN error: unit conversion is missing

Tags: import, implicit-conversion, invoice, acumatica

I am trying to import open Sales Orders through the Acumatica Import Scenario.  I have an excel export that and I am manually assigning to certain fields (including the UOM).  I didn't have any problems importing single line Sales Orders but when I have multiple line items, I get is this error:

```
IN error: unit conversion is missing
```

The UOM is assigned to EACH to both lines and the items are the same in each line of the SO.

I wouldn't think that this would be an issue if you had two line items with the same item on each line.  I might be missing something else, but I am unaware.

Can anyone help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/klZsb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in Import Scenario, hard to determine what exactly is wrong, so, please review your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this error message when my import scenario provided somehow non existent InventoryCD. As outcome, Acumatica wasn't able to initialize UOM column, and gave me mentioned error message.